# Average Intelligence Quotient of Computer Scientists?

Tags: education

Have there been studies measuring the average IQ of successful computer scientists/programmers? The [US military uses the AFQT test](http://isteve.blogspot.com/2013/04/almost-100-million-people-arent-smart.html) to determine intelligence of potential recruits (100 million Americans aren't intelligent enough to be accepted, according to the source). But I know of no similar way to gauge the average IQ makeup of computer scientists/programmers. That a considerable number of them have a facility with math and have degrees doesn't suggest that they are necessarily geniuses, but does suggest they would place much higher than the average person on IQ tests. I've known a few people who have pursued computer programming and have given up, And not for lack of effort but due to what they felt was a lack of brainpower necessary to grasp a language.

Comment: Bounded by $2^x$ for some $x\in\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not necessarily the most robust estimation, and is just a blog post (hence I'm not sure it's reliable enough to do anything real with), but [here is a posting which uses GRE/SAT scores to estimate IQ across different majors](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/25/average-iq-of-students-by-college-major-and-gender-ratio/). It puts the average IQ of CS students at ~124.

[Another blog post](http://motls.blogspot.co.uk/2006/03/iq-in-different-fields.html) uses GRE/SAT scores again to do the estimate, arriving at 128.5 for CS.

Their original data are from [here](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/2010-11_gre_guide.pdf) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20070104093613/http://www.econphd.net/guide.htm), respectively. I haven't puzzled out yet whether they're using the same base data yet.

Undermining these a little is that there are no supporting statistics (again they are just blog posts, not scientific articles).

I would use these results with a great deal of caution. If nothing else, they appear to be heavily biased to the US setting (simply because of the source data), and given the relatively rapid ups and downs of CS popularity, the data for at least one is somewhat old.

Comment: I find it interesting that education is the second lowest on there (109.0). Speaks well for our education system...